# How to redirect to another request mapping of a spring MVC controller from a jsp within a jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, redirect

Situation:
I have a jsp within a jsp. I load another jsp into a div of the outer jsp using .html(). I want to redirect my url into an entirely new url mapping from a controller.

Sample controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/main/submit" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String main(ModelMap model) {
            System.out.println("In controller");

            return "redirect:/anotherJSP";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/anotherJSP" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String anotherJSP(ModelMap model) {
            System.out.println("In another");

            return "anotherJSP";
}
```

Jsp within a jsp:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/main/submit",
    success : function(msg) {
        console.log('redirect');
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("Error.");
    }
});
```

Now, the problem is that the outer jsp stays, and the /anotherJSP url only gets loaded in the innerJSP. I wanted to leave the two jsps and go to the new request mapping URL. Is there anyway I can do it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As I understand it you want it in such a way that it navigates to /anotherJSP when someone goes to /main/submit? And is it necessary for your application that this is done through JS?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example, thats why it does not have any other logic happening. Well, im actually sending data from the inner jsp to/main/submit/ then when the submit is success, it will reload the whole jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect a `POST`.

When you return `redirect:/anotherJSP`, the server sends a redirect instruction back to the web browser, and the browser then sends a new `GET` request for the given URL.

The `GET` request will be for the URL given, with any query parameters. This means that and `POST` payload (data) will be lost.

Change `@RequestMapping(value = { "/anotherJSP" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)` to `@GetMapping("/anotherJSP")` (assuming Spring 4.3 or later).

Comment: Im sorry, i forgot to edit it, the requestmethod is set to GET not POST for another JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Since an ajax call is asynchronous the effect of `return "redirect:/anotherJSP";` is not affecting the browser window, instead you should use window.location.href in your ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/main/submit",
    success : function(msg) {
        console.log('redirect');
        window.location.href = /anotherJSP;
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("Error.");
    }
});
```